# Offsetting Activity layout outside the screen

Tags: android

I'm attempting to replicate the Facebook app's new menu slider.  Creating a slider that comes in from the left is easy enough.  However, the Facebook app takes the Activity's layout and slides it right, with only a small part of its left edge still showing on the right side of the screen.  I'm a bit confused about how to do this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

This best thing I can think of, which I have not tried, is to use the Display class to determine the width of the screen, set the width of the outer-most View to that and display it to the right of the slider (obviously wrapped by a RelativeView).

Update: I've tried the following.

My outer-most View is a RelativeLayout.  Inside this RelativeLayout there are two sibling Views. Both of them are LinearLayouts.  The first one is a layout containing the side bar (in my XML, this is accomplished through an include).  The second one, which sits on top, is a layout containing the main body of the Activity (the screen as I want the user to normally see it).

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainnew_slider"
        layout="@layout/layout_slidermenu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainfeed_mainlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dip"
            android:background="@drawable/titlebar_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dip" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mainfeed_slider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_titlebar_button"
                android:src="@drawable/sidebarico" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="@color/store_toolbar_bottom_border" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the user clicks the ImageButton, I use some animation code to make the main layout move to the right. The code I use to animation the main layout is:

```
        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f
        );
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.0f);
        LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainfeed_mainlayout);
        main.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

When I click the slider button, the two children of the main layout slide to the right, but not the main layout itself (its background stays static).  When the animation is complete, everything snaps back to its original position.

I don't understand why it's not moving the whole main layout and keeping it at its resting place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) applied to your top-level view should do it. Don't do it via layout, it'll be way too slow.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost.  I have a RelativeLayout that contains two LinearLayout children. One of the children is my slider. The other is my main layout.  I've set layout_toRightOf on the main layout to the id of the slider.  The app just crashes.  If I remove layout_toRightOf, the TranslateAnimation brings the slider into view, but the main layout does not get pushed off the right side of the screen as I'm looking to do.

Comment: Re. 'just crashes', there'll be informative exception information in Logcat.

Comment: Don't use layout_toRightOf. Have the slider logically on top of your main layout. It's the main layout that you want to animate to the right, so apply the animation to that rather than to the top-level one that also contains your slider.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've updated the original post to reflect what I've tried so far. Once the animation finishes moving the main layout to the right, the whole thing snaps back to its original position instead of sticking.

Comment: set the fillAfter property to true.

Comment: The next step is closing the slider. When I press on the right edge of the screen (where the main layout is still visible) the touch clearly leaks to the slider layout below. I know this because I have a ScrollView on the slider and I can scroll it by touching this area. I put a view on the slider on this area and made clicking the view scroll the main layout to it's original position. Unfortunately, it's very finicky. It appears the onClick handler will not fire until I've scrolled the ScrollView (........?).

Comment: I've placed a breakpoint in my Activity's onClick handler. It appears clicking the right edge always hits the onClick handler and hits the correct code.  However, the animation doesn't actually happen until the ScrollView is scrolled.  Not sure why.

Comment: Calling "invalidate()" after setting the animation seems to fix it.

Comment: An important detail for Android animations is to remember that the layout is unaffected. If your translateanimation makes a view appear 200px to the right, it hasn't *actually* moved 200px to the right. Touch events etc will behave as if the view was in its original place.

Comment: I've solved the problem by calling bringChildToFront(...) passing in the slider so that its z-order places it as the top-most view. I change it back to the main layout when it closes.  The only problem is this happens immediately instead of after the animation finishes. Is there a way I can make it happen after the animation? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Fixed with AnimationListener :)  If you would, I'd still like to know if you have an alternative solution.